# Atom beautify Trouble

Tags: atom-editor

I recently started learning html, css and using bootstrap, for styling websites.
I was doing a challenge and I pressed the "beautify" shortcut and my code is now all fkd up. Apparently beautify decided to make lines breaks eveywhere...
does anybody know how to fix this mess??
thank you!

```
<
  !--Title-- >

  <
  div class = "row" >
  <
  div class = "col-lg-6" >
  <
  h1 > Meet new and interesting dogs nearby. < /h1> <
button type = "button"
class = "btn btn-dark btn-lg" > < i class = "fab fa-apple" > < /i> Download < /button > <
  button type = "button"
class = "btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" > Download < /button> < /
div > <
  div class = "col-lg-6" >
  <
  img src = "images/iphone6.png"
alt = "iphone-mockup" >
  <
  /div> < /
div > <
  /div> < /
section >
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late for you now, but simply 'undo' the formatting.

<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on a Mac.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows.

Believe me, this shortcut will become your best friend throughout your coding career.

Comment: Thank you, I though so too... :(((((

Comment: Don't worry about it. You're new to programming and you'll come across these stumbling blocks every so often. Just remember that everything is a learning point and you'll do just fine.

Comment: thanks! yeah, I think I've been really practicing my patience at this moment ^^'